# bat file not running an .exe application?

Tags: file, batch-file

I am trying to run an application "VolumeReconstructor.exe" from a bat file, but I get an error

```
'VolumeReconstructor.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

the code is as follows:

```
echo off

::Folder path
set location=D:\pigs_december\Converted_Data\test_data\

::File names
set config_file=PlusConfiguration_mysequence.xml
set image_file=TrackedImageSequence_20191207_172327_ICE_3D_Cubes_Intervall_0_1008.nrrd
::set mask_file=mask.png
::set output_file=Output.nrrd

:: Path to the VolumeReconstructor.exe (PlusTookit --> bin)
cd C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\

:: with mask, but it does not work
::VolumeReconstructor.exe --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --importance-mask-file=%location%\%mask_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
VolumeReconstructor.exe --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4

pause
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run `dir C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\VolumeReconstructor.*` and post ([edit] your post) the results.

Comment: Use `cd /D` rather than `cd` in order to also change the drive if needed...

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it working. Adding the absolute path works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are not currently on the `c:` drive.  You would need to do this:

```
:: Path to the VolumeReconstructor.exe (PlusTookit --> bin)
cd /d C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\

:: with mask, but it does not work
::VolumeReconstructor.exe --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --importance-mask-file=%location%\%mask_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
VolumeReconstructor.exe --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
```

But I would probably recommend using absolute paths like this:

```
:: Path to the VolumeReconstructor.exe (PlusTookit --> bin)
:: don't bother to cd to the directory
:: cd C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\

:: with mask, but it does not work
::VolumeReconstructor.exe --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --importance-mask-file=%location%\%mask_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
"C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\VolumeReconstructor.exe" --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
```

You also might want to double quote all those file locations for future compatibility if you ever change anything to include spaces:

```
:: Path to the VolumeReconstructor.exe (PlusTookit --> bin)
:: don't bother to cd to the directory
:: cd C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\

:: with mask, but it does not work
::VolumeReconstructor.exe --config-file=%location%\%config_file% --source-seq-file=%location%\%image_file% --output-volume-file=%location%\%output_file% --importance-mask-file=%location%\%mask_file% --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
"C:\Users\kristjan\PlusApp-2.9.0.20200316-Win64\bin\VolumeReconstructor.exe" --config-file="%location%\%config_file%" --source-seq-file="%location%\%image_file%" --output-volume-file="%location%\%output_file%" --image-to-reference-transform=ImageToReference --verbose=4
```

Otherwise I have to question whether or not that file is actually in that directory.

Comment: using the absolute path for `VolumeReconstrucor.exe` worked. Thank you!